# c++ - std::getline reads non existing characters

Tags: c++, file, getline

I am currently using Visual Studio 2013.

I have a basic txt file, which has records on each line, and each record are seperated with semicollums in it.For instance:

```
A;James;Jones;N;2;deposit;withdraw
P
A;George;clooney;P;3;deposit;credit;withdraw
P
V
P
A;Charlie;Chaplin;P;2;withdraw;credit
P
V
P
R;Ali;Aksu;N
P
s;Ali;Aksu
E
```

I am using a simple code that I found online, just to print it to the screen:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
ifstream    file("input_file.txt");
string      line;
if (file)
{
    string token;
    stringstream iss;
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        iss << line;
        while (getline(iss, token, ';'))
        {
            cout << token << endl;
        }
        iss.clear();
    }
}
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

But when I run the program, it puts some nonexisting characters in the beginning of the output, this is the first line of the output when compiled on SSH with g++:

> ï»¿A

What is the reason of this, I am trying to use std::getline in a bigger project, but this affects all of the program structure. What is the solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the character encoding for the text file?

Comment: I think it is UTF-8 but how can I be sure about it?

Comment: On GNU/Linux, x86-64, G++ 4.8.4, this works perfectly.

Comment: I only have the Windows option right now,I need that "getline" part to work well to check the other parts of the bigger program, what do you suggest?

Comment: You'll see something like `∩╗┐` (CP 437) or `ï»¿` (CP  1252) when you are looking at UTF-8-encoded text with a BOM. (If you are using a different code page you'll see different character glyphs.) Either open your file in a text editor and remove the UTF-8 BOM, or when you open your file, get rid of the three-byte `"\xEF\xBB\xBF"` BOM at the beginning of the input, if any.

Comment: "when compiled on SSH" <- what do you mean ?!

Comment: You can try to open `input_file.txt` with an hexadecimal editor to see what's really in it. What text editor do you use to edit it ?